# Lubuntu, even Ubuntu Studio... Even after re-instalation, they won't boot!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, lubuntu

Specs:

GPU: ATI 1950XT PCI-E graphics card
CPU: Intel Quad core 2, 64bit, 2.666Ghz, 1333mhz FSB
Mobo: Asus p5kpl/1600 https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5KPL1600/specifications/
 - 8 GB memory installed, but only 4 GB working
 - 4 SATA-II ports
/dev/sda SSD SATA-III 250 GB
/dev/sdb SSD SATA-III 500 GB
/dev/sdc HDD SATA-II  750 GB
All running from Lubuntu 'live' version

I had a special setup in mind because my mainboard (which I bought 2 months ago, is too old! And appears to have everything, but BEFORE the transition to SATA 3, Pci-e 2.0, etc...

So to try to get the most out of the pc, by speed and against boot-up problems..... untill i get laptop I did the following:

- Sda0 => ext4 /boot (boot separated to have less boot failures)
- Sda1 => ext4 /
- Sda2 => Ntfs Windows 7
- Sda3 => Ntfs General Space for backup of my documents, personal files, music, etc!

---

- Sdb0 => Linux swap partition
- Sdb1 => ext4 /home (maybe also /opt added later on)
- Sdb2 => Program files (Non-system oriented programs for windows) + swapfile
- sdb3 => Ntfs (General space for backup of my documents, personal files, music, etc!)

---

My goal is to have both Ubuntu and Windows working so I can switch between both environments.
But also, when one fails.... I can use the other!

The key problem: After I installed Ubuntu studio or Lubuntu... After it wen't to the standard boot-up tests, The bootup process won't go further than the flashing dash and stays that way until oblivion!

What I tried to solve the problem:

- Looked through documentation about the boot-up process and the kinds 
  of boot processes
- Destroyed and recreated the partitions
- Tried to get change through enabling and disabling bootflags
- Tried to install windows 7 instead (GPT problems, while all the partitions are simple primary partitions! Never ever had this problem
  before!)
- I tried to use Geparted live to make partitions
- I tried through KDE Partition manager
- I tried to change the boot order through Bios
- Live CD finds nothing to repair!

All zero luck! How can I get this &*% to work? It's driving me nuts!

I think the major problem started after I tried to reconnect an 3,5 inch sata drive to get the files off it...

Thanks in advance,

Novardi

Comment: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5KPL1600/specifications/ shows the firmware of that motherboard supports a maximum of 4GB memory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: - All the trouble shooting I did was AFTER i connected that Sata drive, but with the Sata drive disconnected ofcourse!
- My mainboard does not support EUFI
- I'm done reading, did nothing but that for the last 2 weeks! Including trying to repair my monitor!
- Spent 200 euro's on my pc to update it a littlebit, without knowing that until now nothing would work!
- Stuck on a ' live' version that resets everything everytime you reboot!
So I found a way out to het it to suspend propperly (it also had problems with going out of suspend....) But still... reboot delet's everything!

Comment: You shouldn't be running 'Live' if you installed Lubuntu or Studio. Download a 'flavour' with a different Desktop (e.g., Lubuntu or Studio) from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . The ISO file should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 .

Comment: Once you make a LiveUSB, install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0.

Comment: Sir, i'm running in ' live'  mode, because that's the only thing that IS working...

Comment: When you perform this  http://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0 installation procedure, what happens? Are you able, once it completes, to reboot, remove the USB Flash drive, and run Ubuntu? If not, what appears on the screen? Please click [edit] and show us what you get.

Comment: Sorry, but i'm getting more and more the idea, that you only understood half of my post ...

!!My mainboard does not have EUFI, thus can' t boot onto GPT!!

- Somehow G-parted live and KDE partitioner formatted the first disk in GPT partitioning.
- Somehow it might be that the partitioning I did DURING one of my previous real installation attempts, Lubuntu went for non-GPT! Because I was able to boot several times into the new installation. Before I came here...
- I think so, because the second disk, which I added during the real installation proces, has NO GPT partitioning!

Comment: Sinds windows 7 also requires Non-GPT, I should also be able to install windows after creating a New Partition table, with Gparted and KDE partition Manager, as MS-dos type.

Comment: Original default for disk partition tables in Windows 7 was MBR, not GPT.

Comment: So again... Looks like you have problems understanding my text. And it's not me, Because from the text you could clearly make-up I was talking about the Ubuntu installation in the first place: Through the use of gparted and the kde partitioner, I unknowingly made GPT partitions!

Comment: o Anyways, I got ubuntu working and was able to install windows too!
All by Creating an MBR partioning table! And within that, through creating new partitions!